# Why are there so many storage transactions when querying an Azure blob storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, powerbi, azure-application-insights

We are investigating using Application Insights.  We have set up a system where we continuously export telemetry from Application Insights to an Azure storage account, where they are stored as blobs.  The continuous export seems to batch up events (JSON objects) so that **each blob tends to contain more than one telemetry event**.

We currently have around 2500 (test) events in the Azure storage account.  They are stored in 280 blobs.

We are using Power BI to query the data from the Azure storage account.  In the case above, I would have expected that querying all the data would amount to around 280 transactions (1 per blob).  Instead, the Azure Portal is telling me that the "total requests" is over 2500, which is similar to the number of events *inside* those blobs.

Any idea why so many requests being made?  This obviously make a big difference as storage transactions are taken into account when calculating the cost of the service.

Comment: It would actually depend on how the read functionality is implemented. A sub-optimal implementation could lead to that. I would recommend using Storage Analytics to see all the storage transactions done against your blob storage account.

Comment: there are some cases where continuous export exports duplicate events, so you might want to verify that internal.data.id is distinct across the blobs. you could also use other tools in the azure portal (like Search or Metrics explorer) to verify your details and see if they match your expectations in export/powerbi

Comment: @GauravMantri our Power BI has one query to fetch the data (other queries reference the end table of this one, so don't connect to Azure again), which it does through AzureStorage.Blobs() -> *Returns a navigational table containing all containers found in the Azure Storage account. Each row has the container name and a link to the container blobs.*. Indeed, the product of this is 280 rows (the blob files), and using fiddler a refresh triggers 1 network request.

Comment: @JohnGardner any idea if whatever the PowerBI call is hitting against is doing something odd on the Azure Blob storage side? It seems weird that Azure flags 2500 blob transactions when it is simply returning the blob files' data. We know there are some duplicate IDs in there from AI's Continuous Exports, but that doesn't seem to be impacting the data returned from Azure.